# ENOSPC Error with Camera Module V3 on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, raspberry-pi-os

I bought an Pi Camera Module 3. I have an Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2.

I get the ENOSPC error when trying to use the camera with raspistill:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o t.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

The Camera is detected by my Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0
```

I also reinstalled the Raspberry Pi OS. I used Raspberry Pi OS (32 Bit) normal version and lite version. (Always did update it)

Is the camera (or even the camera interface on the pi) defect or can I test something else?

---

Maybe useless but more information:

```
 raspistill -v

"raspistill" Camera App (commit e39c6354b784 Tainted)

Camera Name imx708
Width 4608, Height 2592, filename (null)
Using camera 0, sensor mode 0

GPS output Disabled

Quality 85, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Time delay 5000, Timelapse 0
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Comment: You cannot use the legacy camera stack (raspixxx) with the new v3 camera

Comment: ok, how do I use the camera then, do you have a link to a tutorial or sth else?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I attempt to use subprocess.Popen(['raspivid', '-t', '3000']) in a python program.

If I use the exact same Popen command in another program that does nothing bu the Popen commmand, it works.  raspivid also always works using the command line.

I am using an updated Bullseye on a Zero 2W with an HQ camera.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/129974)

Answer (score 0):

**Same hardware** here and first I did not get it to work too.

**The important fact: `raspistill` and his siblings are not supported for Camera Modules v3+**

In `raspi-config` you can also disable legacy camera support because it's not being used anyway.

Now I'm not absolutely sure and it may heavily depend on the Raspbian version you are running:

If `rpicam-still` command is available, just try to call it: `rpicam-still -o test.jpg`.
Or if you are on a desktop you can use: `rpicam-hello` which should open a window preview for 5 seconds.

If you don't have `rpicam-apps` installed or still have issues and it looks like it's not on the repositories (dang!), you have to compile these packages manually.

On my first attempt I tried on an existing Buster image but the compilation failed: [Bug report and info](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpicam-apps/issues/616). May apply to Bullseye and also Buster, you should uninstall these packages first (if they are installed of course):

```
sudo apt remove libcamera-apps-lite libcamera0
```

If you don't uninstall `libcamera0` it may be outdated and being used for compilation of `rpicam-apps` instead of your freshly compiled `libcamera`.

Then just follow the official build and install instructions:
[Building libcamera](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#building-libcamera)

Make sure to build and install `libcamera` and then finally `rpicam-apps`. They're on the same page. I've followed the instructions for "Raspi OS Lite" and I chose to use `-Dneon_flags=armv8-neon` because I compiled for a Pi3.
I've skipped the `libepoxy` section.

I've spent some hours and now I'm too lazy to redo all steps including compiling on Buster. Please be nice and add comments if you are sure what problem was on your Pi including the OS version. Thank you.